# Working of NAND gate using diodes and transistors

Tags: digital-logic

[image]
I found this circuit which is used to construct a NAND gate. Although I understand the working of AND, OR, and NOT gates constructed using diodes and transistors, I just cannot understand the working of this NAND gate circuit at all. Any help would be highly appreciated.

P.S. : What is the function of the diodes D3 and D4 shown in the diagram?

Comment: Install 47pF across those 2 diodes, and notice how the delay times change.

Answer (score 4):

D3 and D4 are there to provide a voltage drop of about 650 mV each when forward biased. Does this provide enough of a hint to understand the rest of the circuit?

Note that D1 and D2 also have an implicit forward voltage drop. What does this imply about noise margins at the base of the transistor?

Answer (score 2):

D3 and D4 are there to ensure that the BJT turns off properly. Put another way, using the conventional "basic" model of a BJT, 0.7 volts is needed to drive current into the base and, with the two extra diodes, the voltage at the junction of D1, D2 and D3 would need to be 2.1 volts before the BJT starts to activate.

With A and B inputs at 5 volts (logic 1) both D1 and D2 conduct zero current and the base is fed current through R0, D3, D4 and R1 - this turns on the BJT and the output is largely zero volts. If either input goes low, the junction of D1 and D2 falls to about 0.7 volts and the base current is thoroughly turned-off. This causes the output to rise to a logic 1 level.

Comment: Now I get it !  D3 and D4 are there to give the transistor a proper turn-off state, and it turns on only when the combined effect of D1, D2, and D3 gives the base a potential of 2.1 (3 times 0.7) volts. Thank you.

Comment: @Jasmine - Close enough. Plus, consider what this says about the logic levels of the inputs A and B. What voltages are required to affect the output? The base current is set by R0, R1 and D1 and D2. This, combined with the transistor gain determines the current level at the collector of the transistor. Consider how much current is required to pull A or B low. This combines with the transistor current to determine how many subsequent inputs the output can control - it's called fan-out.